# How can I fix the Azure deployment error for my React JS app with Docker?

Tags: reactjs, azure, docker, dockerfile

Not able to deploy react js app to Azure with Docker

This is my docker file

```
FROM node:14 as build-stage

WORKDIR /frontend
COPY package.json .

RUN npm install --force
COPY . .

RUN npm run build

# Stage 2: Serve the built React app with a lightweight web server
FROM nginx:1.21-alpine as production-stage

# Copy the built app from the build stage to the production stage
COPY --from=build-stage /frontend/build /usr/share/nginx/html

# Expose port 
EXPOSE 80

# Start the Nginx web server
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Created the docker image using `docker build -t my-react-image:latest .`

Ran the docker image using `docker run -p 80:80 my-react-image:latest`

After that, pushed the image to Azure, however when I deploy it, it displays the following screen
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFyaR.png)

Note: Also tried exposing 3000 in the docker file and added the variable WEBSITES_PORT in application settings and added value as 3000, still getting the same error.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Comment: What does "to Azure" mean? An app service? How is the app service configured? Have you looked at logs?

Comment: Can you try enabling the [diagnostic logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#enable-application-logging-linuxcontainer) on your app service contianer and review the log stream logs.

Comment: @DanielMann, yes, it's an app service and in the logs getting exec /docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error in the logs

Comment: @VenkateshDodda, checked in log stream and this is the error I am getting - exec /docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error. However, the same docker image works fine in my M1 chip laptop

Answer (score 0):

***When I tried to run my deployed reactjs application, I was also getting the same Application error.***

---

I have created a sample reactjs application, dockerized and deployed to Azure App service:

***Note the port number of your application:*** (the same port number should be updated in WEBSITES_PORT under Application settings in portal)

[image]

**Local Output:**

[image]

**My Dockerfile:**

```
# Use an existing Node.js image as the base image
FROM node:14-alpine

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the package.json and package-lock.json files into the container
COPY package*.json ./

# Install the dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of the application files into the container
COPY . .

# Build the React application
RUN npm run build

# Expose port 80 for the container
EXPOSE 80

# Start the server
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

**Building Docker Image:**

[image]

**Pushing Docker Image:**

[image]

To check the status if the application is deployed or to check the error details if failed to deploy:

*Go to App Service-> Deployed Center-> Logs*

[image]

I was also getting ***Application error*** when tried to run the deployed application:

[image]

***Fix:***

To resolve the error:

1. Enabled logging in App Service:
   *Web Application-> Monitoring-> App Service Logs-> Select *File System* in Application Logging:*

[image]

2. Go to *Application settings* in *Configuration*-> add WEBSITES_PORT and port number as its value:

- My Application is listening to `Port_Number:3000`, so I have added the settings as shown below:

[image]

***Restart the application after updating the above settings.***

**Portal:**

Running the deployed application:
[image]

***If none of the above steps work, re-deploy the application and try to run again.***

Comment: Still getting the same error even after adding WEBSITES_PORT in application settings, can you share your docker file for reference

Comment: @vasudevpareek, Updated the answer with my dockerfile for your reference.

Comment: but @PravallikaKV in dockerfile you have exposed to 80